# Icons in iOS6 targeted app while uploading to the App Store

Tags: ios, icons, app-store

We've just uploaded our new iPad app in iTunes connect. It's waiting for review now.
The app is built with base SDK 6 but, sure, it was tested under iOS7 and it works fine.
I've received some warnings during the upload connected with missing icon files:

*Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format.*

Can that be a problem for the approve? As I said the app is built with the target SDK 6 so I'm not sure that I can add these missing icon files in the project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my personal experience, it will not be a cause of rejection. But it is good practice to add them for future release.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've decided to add missing icons and to re-upload the app. But I've found a lot of information from developers which had such experience as yours.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a problem. iOS 7 sizes are [required](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html) even if you target SDK 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will more then likely get your app rejected. I theory you shouldn't submit your app to the Apple Review process if it contains errors or warnings as these will be instead reject. By the looks of things you are supporting both iPad and iPhone so you have made a Universal app. So you need to provide all icons for iOS 6 and iOS 7 on iPhone and iPad otherwise they will appear white on the device. As `amb` has already supplied read through the [Icon and Images Size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html)

You should really be supplying icons for all of the options in the image

[image]